# Run NUnit 2.5.5 tests from within Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and using .NET 4.0 code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, nunit

How can I do it?

All the test runners seem to work for VS2008 but not 2010 and if they do, not for .NET 4.

Thanks

Comment: are there any tools you are trying to use to run the tests? for example Resharper Test Runner or TestDriven.Net?

Comment: I don't have a license. It needs to be free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestDriven.net personal works like a champ. :)

[link text](http://www.testdriven.net/)

Comment: Thanks. I have been meaning to try tdd as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried MBUnit?
That is free from http://www.MBUnit.com
May be worth a try as part of the Gallio suite.